# If $f(z)$ is analytic at $z_0$, does it follow that $f''(z)$ is also analytic at $z_0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am a student of physics. Most of my knowledge about complex analysis is based on the book Complex Variables and Applications by Brown and Churchill.

By definition, if $f(z)$ is a complex analytic/holomorphic/monogenic function at $z_0$, $f'(z)$ has a unique derivative in some neighborhood around $z_0$ i.e. $|z-z_0|<\delta$. Does it follow that $f''(z)$ (and therefore, all the higher derivatives) is also analytic at $z_0$? Can we prove this?

Comment: Yes, it can be proven. One way is as a consequence of [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula). It looks like in the article they also make the comment of this statement and how the argument goes.

Comment: What am I missing? Without knowing $f$ is analytic on some neighbourhood, we can’t make sense of $f’’$ as that requires knowledge of $f’$ all over some neighbourhood. But given analyticity on some neighbourhood, we know $f$ has derivatives of all order (nearby $z_0$)

Comment: That from asserting existence of the derivative, the existence of further derivatives is a different statement and thus requires a proof. The proof is not trivial either. Or maybe you are missing that when analyticity is given it always comes in open sets, by definition.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You can differentiate the power series termwise.

In the case of a complex variable,  once differentiable (holomorphic) implies infinitely differentiable (and holomorphic and analytic are equivalent).

Comment: My question is, how do you prove that? Is the proof very intricate?

Comment: @Solidification intricacy is in the eye of the beholder but I would say it's part of a stack of theorems that occupies a couple weeks of an undergrad course, the key ideas in which are the cauchy-goursat theorem and the cauchy integral formula.

Answer (score 0):

You probably know that in the analytic case, there are coefficients $a_k$ such that
$$
f(z) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_k (z-z_0)^k
$$
holds for all $z \in B_\delta(z_0)$ (and the series converges, *of course*). There is a multitude of arguments to show why convergent power series can be differentiated arbitrarily often (and the derivatives are convergent power series, too). In fact it holds that
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} f(z) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}a_k (z-z_0)^k
$$
and so on for higher derivatives.

Just tell me whether you need a reference for the specific arguments.